# Remove obj from scroll able list when selected

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 2 scroll able lists, list1 and list2.

Both with same objects on the lists but I need to remove the obj from list 2 when it is selected in list 1.

This is my Code:

```
   private void displayList2()
   {
      Car selectedCar = (Car)list1.getSelectedValue(); //gets the selected value from list1 which is working fine.
      List<String> carsData = new ArrayList<String>();
      for (Car eachcar : cars)
      {
          if (cars.equals(selectedCar))
          {
              list2.remove(selectedCar);
          }
      }
   }
```

It currently getSelectedValue from a scrollable list (list1) which works fine but it does not remove from list 2

EDIT:

I have now altered the code a bit to look like this but still does not work:

```
   private void displayList2()
       {
          Car selectedCar = (Car)list1.getSelectedValue(); //gets the selected value from list1 which is working fine.
          List<String> carsData = new ArrayList<String>();
          for (Car eachcar : cars)
          {
              if (carsData.equals(selectedCar))
              {
              carsData.remove(selectedCar);
          }
      list2.setListData(cars);
      }
      list2.setSelectedIndex(0);
   }
```

There are no errors being displayed and both scroll able lists works and the selectedIndex is at 0 but when clicking on the list1 it still does not remove the object from list2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check the equality between the `List` of `Car` and a `Car`:

```
 if (cars.equals(selectedCar))
```

It will never be `true`.

You should rather compare the selected `Car` with the current `Car` of the iteration :

```
 if (eachcar.equals(selectedCar))
```

After your edit, I think that you need is removing the data from the JList 
To do it, use an iterator to remove the selected element in `cars` :

```
 for (Iterator<Car> it = cars.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
     Car eachcar = it.next();
     if (eachcar.equals(selectedCar)){
        it.remove();
     }
 }
```

Then after the loop, invoke  `list2.setListData(cars);` to update the content of the JList.

Comment: no suitable method found for remove(Car)
    method Component.remove(MenuComponent) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Car cannot be converted to MenuComponent)

Comment: This worked thankyou @davidxxx one small typo though. chars.iterator(); is cars.iterator();

Comment: You are welcome. Writing without compiler may sometimes create this kind of typo :)